# How to compress beta to a specified beta_0 with Lasso from scikit-learn?

Tags: lasso-regression

LASSO is aiming at minizing 1/2*||y- X * \beta||_2^2 + \lambda * ||\beta||_1. But I need to make \beta be as close as possible to a specified \beta_0, which is already known. That is minizing 1/2*||y- X * \beta||_2^2 + \lambda * ||\beta - \beta_0||_1, while constraining \beta > 0.

I tried two options:

1. make \beta - \beta_0 a new \beta*, and use Lasso to get it, but this can't guarantee \beta > 0.
2. modify the source code of LASSO from scikit-learn, but when I followed code to _fast_cd I got lost.
   I'm not a experienced python coder, so if someone can give me some guide?

Thanks in advance